# Can the Python interpreter be updated using 'PIP'

Tags: python, pip

just like we install packages like Matplotlib, using pip command in the cmd (pip install matplotlib) can we also update to newer version of python by some pip command?

Comment: No. pip is designed to manage **packages** not interpreters.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Pip is designed for managing python packages and **not python versions** to update Python you must download the version you wish from their [site in the download selection.](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

## Simple Answer

No you cannot

Comment: Should i uninstall the previous version before installing the new one? or it will overwrite?